# CSV module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I finished the Ruby chapter in [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/titles/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks). It tries to make you familiar with the core concepts of several languages rather quickly. Dutifully I did all exercises, but most likely they can be improved to be more Ruby-like.

> Given: a CSV file structured with a first line with headers and
>   subsequent rows with data.
>
> ```
> one, two
> lions, tigers
> ```
>
> Create a module which loads the header and values from a CSV file,
>   based on the name of the implementing class. (RubyCSV ->
>   "rubycsv.txt") Support an `each` method which returns a `CsvRow`
>   object. Use `method_missing` to return the value for the column for a
>   given heading. E.g. usage which will print "lions":
>
> ```
> m = RubyCsv.new
> m.each { |row| p row.one }
> ```

My implementation:

```
class CsvRow
  attr :row_hash

  def initialize( row_hash )
    @row_hash = row_hash
  end

  def method_missing( name, *args )
    @row_hash[ name.to_s ]
  end
end

module ActsAsCsv
  attr_accessor :headers, :csv_contents

  def self.included( base )
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_csv
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def read
      @csv_contents = []
      filename = self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt'
      file = File.new( filename )
      @headers = file.gets.chomp.split( ', ' )

      file.each do |row|
        @csv_contents << row.chomp.split( ', ' )
      end
    end               

    def initialize
      read
    end

    def each      
      @csv_contents.each do |content|        
        hash = {}
        @headers.zip( content ).each { |i| hash[ i[0] ] = i[1] }
        yield CsvRow.new hash
      end
    end
  end
end

class RubyCsv  # No inheritance! You can mix it in.
  include ActsAsCsv
  acts_as_csv
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def method_missing( name, *args )
  @row_hash[ name.to_s ]
end
```

Doing it like this means that if the user calls a row method with arguments, the arguments will silently be ignored. Also if the user calls any method which does not exist and for which no row exists either, he'll just get back nil. I think in both cases an exception should be thrown, so I'd implement `method_missing` like this:

```
def method_missing( name, *args )
  if @row_hash.has_key?(name.to_s)
    if args.empty?
      @row_hash[ name.to_s ]
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments(#{ args.size } for 0)"
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

---

```
module ActsAsCsv
  # ...

  def self.included( base )
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_csv
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

This setup seems needlessly complicated. Since all `acts_as_csv` does is include the instance methods (except `headers` and `csv_contents`, which will be present even if `acts_as_csv` is not called - which seems a bit arbitrary to me) and there is no reason why a user would want to include `ActsAsCsv` without getting the instance methods, I see no reason for `acts_as_csv` to exist at all. The instance methods should be directly in the `ActsAsCsv` module and the `ClassMethods` and `InstanceMethods` modules should not exist.

This way the code will be less complex, and you only need one line `include ActsAsCsv` instead of two to enable the CSV functionality.

---

```
def read
  @csv_contents = []
  filename = self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt'
  file = File.new( filename )
  @headers = file.gets.chomp.split( ', ' )

  file.each do |row|
    @csv_contents << row.chomp.split( ', ' )
  end
end
```

First of all you're opening a file and never closing it. You should use `File.open` with a block instead.

Second of all you should make use of higher order functions like `map`. Using `map` you can create `@csv_contents` like this instead of appending to it in an `each` loop:

```
def read
  filename = self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt'
  file = File.open( filename ) do |file|
    @headers = file.gets.chomp.split( ', ' )
    @csv_contents = file.map {|row| row.chomp.split( ', ' )}
  end
end
```

---

That being said I don't think it's a good idea to read the whole file into memory in advance (or at all), as that will make your library unusable on big files (which might not even fit into memory).

So I would get rid of the `read` method and just open and read through the file in the `each` method, like this:

```
def each
  filename = self.class.to_s.downcase + '.txt'
  File.open(filename) do |file|
    headers = file.gets.chomp.split( ', ' )
    file.each do |content|        
      hash = {}
      headers.zip( content.chomp.split(', ') ).each { |i| hash[ i[0] ] = i[1] }
      yield CsvRow.new hash
    end
  end
end
```

---

Lastly, instead of

```
hash = {}
headers.zip( content ).each { |i| hash[ i[0] ] = i[1] }
```

You can also write `hash = Hash[ headers.zip( content ) ]`.

---

On a more general note, your code does not really correctly parse CSV files. Your code assumes that the fields will be separated by a comma followed by a single space. However it is not required that commas are actually followed by any spaces (and the RFC actually says that any space after a comma is part of the field's content and should not be ignored). You're also not handling quoting (e.g. `foo, "bar, baz", bay`, which is a row containing three, not four, fields) at all.

Comment: Actually this question is an adaptation of an example in the book. The `each` and `CsvRow` needed to be added. Now that I heard your explanation I find it a bad example, or ill explained. Others apparently thought the same. I'm definitely going to attempt some more metaprogramming in Ruby to see whether I can grasp its added value. I just need to come up with a nice relatively small exercise. :)

Comment: Found [the authors explanation](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/147/topics/4654). _"This was another case of editing an exercise getting the best of me. I wanted to show how Rails acts-as modules work, and initially I had some dynamic capabilities that did some introspection. But in the end, I simplified the application and removed the very capabilities (faster-csv style attribute inspection) that made acts-as a good idea.

I’ll address it in the second edition."_

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers! They've been really useful. I fixed some minor mistakes in your updated code samples, but your explanation was great. ;p

Comment: @Steven: Yeah, I wasn't thinking with the `each` instead of `map` ;-)  Btw: I've added a paragraph at the end.